# How do I solve the "Reference rewriter: Error: type `System.Web.HttpUtility` doesn't exist in target framework" error in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, package, augmented-reality, hololens

I have tried everything that I found on the internet, and nothing worked.

I have an AR Unity project, made in Unity 3D for the HoloLens 2 that deployed perfectly fine, until I added this package: https://localjoost.github.io/Positioning-QR-codes-in-space-with-HoloLens-2-building-a-%27poor-man%27s-Vuforia%27/

These two projects work separately, but once I add the package to my project, I get all of those errors below. The build succeeds, but the project doesn't work. The project should ask for permission to access my camera once I open it on HoloLens, but it doesn't, and nothing happens. These are the errors; I get 15 in total with the first two being the majority of those:

```
Reference rewriter: Error: type `System.Web.HttpUtility` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from RestSharp.dll at System.String RestSharp.Extensions.StringExtensions::HtmlDecode(System.String).
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1219)
PostProcessWinRT:Process () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:209)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)

Reference rewriter: Error: method `System.String System.Web.HttpUtility::HtmlDecode(System.String)` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from RestSharp.dll at System.String RestSharp.Extensions.StringExtensions::HtmlDecode(System.String).
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1219)
PostProcessWinRT:Process () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:209)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)

Reference rewriter: Error: method `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection System.Web.HttpUtility::ParseQueryString(System.String)` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from RestSharp.dll at RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth.OAuthWebQueryInfo RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth.OAuthWorkflow::BuildProtectedResourceInfo(System.String,RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth.WebParameterCollection,System.String).
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1219)
PostProcessWinRT:Process () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:209)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
```

Here are all of the things I have tried already:

1. Changed the API compatibility from .NET 4.x to .NET Standard 2.0, as suggested in a different thread. Unfortunately, this threw worse errors and didn't even lead to a successful build.
2. Added a csc.rps file with the one line: -r:System.Web.dll. Unfortunately, this did nothing and was the answer suggested by many in many forums and Unity's official forum.
3. I also tried adding different lines to the csc.rps file, but nothing changed.
4. Also asked chatgpt, which didn't really help.

I am currently using Unity 2019.4.24f1, and I can't change the version I am using. My build settings for Unity are ARM64 and D3D. I deploy to the Hololens via VisualStudio2019 using the Master, ARM64, and Device settings.

Comment: use unitys webrequest class?

Comment: @BugFinder How do I do that, because these errors are not from any scripts that I have created or that were in the package. When I click on it, it doesn't redirect me to anything

Comment: Then the package doesnt sound like it was designed for unity - its using c# specific features, not unity enabled ones.

Comment: I see, but that's odd because it works fine on its own if I don't package it as a package but just use the Unity project directly from the link. I exported it as a package and imported it into mine because theoretically I think it should work fine. I made sure to use the same unity version.

Comment: @user168356 if this uses API only available in Windows standalone (which I assume your UnityEditor is running on) but not in UWP then it will not work this way ... DLLs are built for a specific platform and environment and don't simply work everywhere ;)

Comment: @derHugo Even if both projects work exported as UWP projects?